# How to return a record from SQL Server DB and display the values in readonly textboxes using ASP.NET webforms?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, data-binding, webforms

I am a newbie, and not really sure how to approach this issue.  My application will be prompting a user for an employee ID number in a textbox.  I want to take that employee id and return the record for the employee id and display the values in read only text boxes.  What is the best way to do this.  How would I return the record and bind the info to the textboxes.  Thanks.

Comment: @brain this not a forum to ask for desired code. here you ask your help if you run into error. you shows you effort in order to fulfill your approach. but, as you are newbie you may find this [helpful](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/72d20e/fetch-row-records-from-database-table-on-a-button-click/). Also this might help in [future](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the information and the link to a resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
text='<%#Eval("YOUR COLUMN NAME") %>'
```